# SELECT TOP que traga todos os resultados, algo como TOP all, existe no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Durante meus estudos, tentei ordenar os registros e colocando os que são `NULL` no final, fiz do seguinte modo:

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.firstname,
    tbl1.mgrid
FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 firstname, mgrid
        FROM HR.Employees
        WHERE mgrid IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY mgrid  
    ) tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    tbl2.firstname,
    tbl2.mgrid
FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP 100 firstname, mgrid
        FROM HR.Employees
        WHERE mgrid IS NULL
        ORDER BY mgrid  
    ) tbl2
```

Eu não tinha interesse em colocar o `TOP`, porém descobri que ao usar uma query dentro do `FROM`, é obrigatório colocar o `TOP` (pelo menos na versão que uso), acontece que o `TOP` espera um parâmetro de quantidade, mas eu não tenho uma quantidade fixa, ai eu gostaria de saber se existe algo como `SELECT TOP all`.

Obrigado!

Comment: nunca vi ser obrigatório TOP em um sub-select, explica melhor isso aí

Comment: eu também não acredito que seja necessário. Mas você pode usar o modificador `PERCENT` para especificar que você quer uma percentagem, e não um número fixo. Daí é só fazer `SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT`.

Comment: Gabriel, na subconsulta o TOP foi solicitado porque você colocou ORDER BY nela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando [TOP()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql) tem como objetivo limitar as linhas retornadas em um conjunto, portanto não faz sentido utilizá-lo para retornar todas as linhas.

**TOP (Transact-SQL)**:

> Limita as linhas retornadas em um conjunto de resultados de consulta a um número ou percentual de linhas

Outra questão é que não há necessidade de fazer dois `select` para separar os registros e depois unilos novamente apenas com o intuito de ordená-los. Você consegue resolver o seu problema apenas colocando um `CASE WHEN` no seu `order by`, veja o exemplo abaixo:

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/34cac/10):

```
SELECT firstname, mgrid
FROM Employees
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN mgrid IS NULL 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
   END
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]